# How can I reliably redirect a user in my angular app, without any hackiness?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

Sometimes mysteriously throughout my working with angular projects, redirecting to different routes / states (in the case of `ui-router` projects) simply does not work. No errors in console, the line of code to perform the redirect **does** get hit in my browser (verified via step-through), but sometimes the redirect just doesn't work.

I've tried the following methods,

1 `$state.go('stateName');` (using `ui-router`),

2 `$location.path('/url');` (using built-in angular routing)

3 `window.location.href = '/#/url'` (hacky plain javascript method that reloads the page and doesn't take advantage of DI or any other angular niceties)

I was informed via another SO question that it has something to do with the angular `$digest` cycle, and that I had to perform location redirects at the end of a cycle.

People have suggested workarounds such as:

- wrapping your redirects in an arbitrary `setTimeout` or `$timeout`, to force it to happen at the end of the current `$digest` cycle. This is just bad, not DRY, and an annoying hack (but it does work).
- calling `$scope.apply();` immediately after the redirect code, which is also bad because you often get cases of "digest already in progress", etc etc. And, as with the above hack, it's not DRY and is an annoying hack.

So, my question is: how do I **guarantee** a redirect will happen (whether via plain javascript, `$location`, `$state.go` or anything else I may be unaware of) in one simple line of code?

Comment: To guarantee a redirect, instead of fighting against Angular's $digest cycle, I would find a way to work with it. Anything you try to do to guarantee a redirect inside Angular without understanding it, will be a hack. Do you have any examples you could put up that don't work?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your navigation call using a service:

```
angular.module('app').service('navigation', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  return { 
    navigate: function (url) {
      $location.path(url);
      $rootScope.apply();
    }
  }
}])
```

or with `$timeout` if you prefer:

```
angular.module('app').service('navigation', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  function go(){
    $location.path(this.url);
  }

  return { 
    navigate: function (url) {
      this.url = url;
      $timeout(go.bind(this));
    }
  }
}])
```

Then inject your service and call:

```
navigation.navigate(url);
```

The problem is that you're stuck with either `$timeout` or `$scope.apply` if you want angular to acknowledge calls that originate from outside of the angular digest cycle (like DOM events), so any solution you come up with will have to incorporate one of the two.